# How to encrypt a file buffer with XOR?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read in a file to buffer and encrypt each byte with my XOR encryption key. I have implemented it like the following but it segfaults for some reason.

```c
int main(char argc, char *argv[]) {
    fileIn = fopen("data.bin", "rb"); // open input file (binary)
    if (fileIn==NULL) {
        puts("Error opening input file");
        exit (1);
    }

    // obtain file size.
    fseek(fileIn , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(fileIn);
    rewind(fileIn);
    printf("Filesize: %d bytes.\n", lSize);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file.
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        puts("malloc for input file buffer failed (not enough memory?)");
        exit (2);
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer.
    fread (buffer, 1, lSize, fileIn);

    char *enckey = "enckey123";

    unsigned char *buf = buffer;
    int index = 0;
    while (buf < buf + lSize - 1) {
        *buf++ ^= enckey[index++ % 9]; // 9 is the length of the encryption key
    }
}
```

It segfaults right at this like `*buf++ ^= enckey[index++ % 9];`.

Debugging with gdb, I can see that `lSize` is something like 2000, but `index` has the value of 128585.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `buf < buf + lSize - 1` can never be false if `lSize` is positive, for the same reason the mathematical inequality *x* < *x* + *h* is always true when *h* is positive. You want `buf < buffer + lSize` or simply `index < lSize`.

Comment: Instead of doing `fseek` + `ftell` to get the file size followed by your `rewind` call, you can simply invoke [fstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) to get the file size after you invoke fopen.

Comment: Your code fails because your variable naming is silly. Had you renamed `buf` to `current_position` or similar you'd have noticed it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop:

```
while (buf < buf + lSize - 1) {
```

never finishes.

Perhaps you meant

```
while (buf < buffer + lSize) {
```

?

P.S. the -1 means it doesn't encrypt the last character.

Comment: In addition, the segfault is happening because, since the loop never ends, `buf` is eventually incremented past the end of the allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will never end.

I think the loop needs a better way to iterate over only `lSize` bytes.
I did it by changing the last few lines to this:

```
    // ...
    // Calculate where to stop the iteration
    const unsigned char *buf_end = buf + lSize - 1;
    // Walk over lSize bytes in the buffer
    while (buf < buf_end) {
        *buf++ ^= enckey[index++ % 9]; // 9 is the length of the encryption key
    } 
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, but I think this is more readable:

Instead of this:

```
while (buf < buf + lSize - 1) {
    *buf++ ^= enckey[index++ % 9]; // 9 is the length of the encryption key
}
```

This:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lSize; i++) {
   buf[i] = enckey[i % 9];
}
```